# Coming to conclusion of the big O notation for binary search

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

While mathematically finding the complexity of the binary search algorithm, We actually assume that there are 2<sup>K</sup> elements in the list. During the process we come to this particular part and the statement in my book:

"Hence, at most 2K + 2 = 2logn + 2 comparisons are required to perform a binary search when the list being searched has 2<sup>K</sup> elements. (If n is not a power of 2, the original list is expanded to a list with 2<sup>K+1</sup> terms, where k = ⌊logn⌋, and the search requires at most 2 $\lceil logn\rceil $ + 2 comparisons.) Consequently, a binary search requires at most ϴ(logn) comparisons. "

There is one thing I do not understand in this:

1)How is this algorithm a ϴ(logn)? From what I understand a big ϴ is only when it is both big **O and big Ω**, but where are the functions, f(x) and g(x) such that f(x) is both **O(g(x))  as well as Ω(g(x))**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a $\Theta$ result for the worst case complexity, you basically want to furnish the worst case (which gives an $\Omega$ result, i.e. a lower bound on the worst case runtime) and prove it is the worst case (which gives an $O$ result, i.e. an upper bound on the worst case runtime). It may be easier to proceed in the other order: determine from the structure of the algorithm what the worst possible case could ever be, and then construct an input that leads to this behavior.

For binary search on $2^K$ elements, the worst case situation would be $K$ halvings of the array, because at that point there is only one element left (so you merely check whether it is the element you want and then you're done). That gives an $O$ result. To get an $\Omega$ result you can furnish an array of size $2^K$ and an element to search for so that binary search actually takes $K$ halvings, or perhaps just a little bit less. Hint: put the desired element in the second position and nowhere else.

Comment: I don't really get it, how is Ω the worst case? If it is the lower bound, isn't it basically saying, "for a certain x > k, for the number of elements n, the minimum number of search is given by g(n)". (At least , i've understood it like this, {I just study from books, please note me where I'm wrong.")

Comment: @BeshalJaenal You are trying to bound the worst case runtime both above and below. The upper bound is the $O$, the lower bound is the $\Omega$. You can get a lower bound on the worst case by just producing an example, whereas an upper bound on the worst case requires a proof using the structure of the algorithm. So here, the upper bound is saying "it can't take more than $K$ halvings" while the lower bound is producing an array and search item that actually require $K$ halvings.

Comment: I'm not getting it technically. Are you saying the worst case analysis doesn't have to have an upper bound? Because, you mention " You are trying to ........", I thought, am I doing wrong trying to bind it?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal It does have an upper bound. For a lower bound, you need to produce an example where the runtime is at least some amount, because the worst case is at least as bad as any example you produce. The upper bound is where the analysis really takes place.

Comment: @BeshalJaenal No, when I said "you are trying to ..." I was not saying "where your mistake is is in trying to ..." I was saying the actual correct goal of the analysis.

Comment: you must be meaning things in general. But, in this case, for the binary search algorithm, Why is the algorithm deduced to be  ϴ(logn)? I understand how procedurally the author step by step analyzes the algorithm, but there's nothing about the lower bound, and for that we do not even know that the lower bound is some constant multiple of logn.

Comment: In the passage you quoted the author did not do this part of the analysis, but it is not hard to do. See my hint.

Comment: would it be correct to say that, the upper bound is: 2 $\lceil logn\rceil $ + 2, and the lower bound function is: 2⌊logn⌋+2 and also, the function for our algorithm is actually: 2logn+2, which is obviously less than the first and more than the second function, and hence we could deduce that it is Theta logn.   Would it be correct?

Comment: Don't bother to exactly compute the worst case time. It is not useful. Just note that at worst you need K halvings and that there is a case that uses K halvings. Then (since it is perhaps not obvious that a halving can be done in constant time), count comparisons in the case of K halvings. Then do whatever you need to adapt this to a length that isn't a power of 2.

Comment: would knowing how to calculate this help when we would develop our own algorithms? (Someday):-)

Comment: what I did above, was it correct?

Comment: Knowing how to determine the $\Theta$ asymptotic for the runtime? Yes, that's useful. Knowing how to compute the *exact* worst case runtime is hopeless in the case of most algorithms, and it's usually not useful anyway because the leading order term usually already dominates by the time you get to a case large enough to give it to a computer.

Comment: What you wrote three comments back was basically correct, assuming that each halving requires $2$ comparisons. But again such fine details are not required. You should simply say that at most $\lceil \log(n) \rceil$ halvings are required and that a halving takes $\Theta(1)$ comparisons to calculate.

Comment: (Cont.) This approach also avoids sensitivity to implementation details; for instance I disagree that binary search's leading order term is $2\log(n)$ comparisons. I'd say it's $\log(n)$ comparisons, because in my implementation I would remember the result of a comparison that I already did. Thus if I have 16 elements, and I know that the search item is smaller than the 8th element and bigger than the first, I don't recompare the search item with the first element. I just go straight to the 4th element.

Comment: by hopeless, in the first of your latest 3 comments, do you mean , it's too hard to come to these results for most algorithms?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal To come to *exact* formulas for numbers of steps, that's right.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's most of what I wanted to understand. Thanks! :-)

Comment: one additional thought, if you'd like to answer. Are these used for benchmarking?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal Yes. You can also use benchmarking to check these kinds of theoretical results. For example, try running binary search on inputs of size $n=1000,2000,\dots,10000$, putting the target in the second position every time. Time the results and plot the time against the size. You should see a perfect logarithmic shape. (These examples need to be a little bit large because smaller examples will be done so fast that your timing will not be accurate.)

Comment: in a more commercial kind of software analysis part, are things done statistically as you've given above(plotting) or from theoritical conceptual proofs? Or both perhaps?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal In general both. I'm not in software engineering but I doubt that people use theoretical analysis to estimate the performance of an *entire program*. Instead they would use it to estimate the performance of some of the individual functions. Extending this to the whole program is difficult because you'd need to know how often the individual functions get called.